# In stored procedure not getting expected result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables `Surveys`, `RightsonSurveys` and `Users`.

I want the result as shown in the screenshot below where all survey list should be shown but only those surveys should be checked where user has `IsViewer` or `IsAuthor` is true:

[image]

But instead, I'm getting this result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the `RightsOnSurveys` table I am providing permissions to access particular surveys. For this I have created a view like this:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vRightsOnSurveys]
AS
    SELECT
        ID SurveyID, 0 ID, -1 UserID, 
        CAST(1 AS bit) IsViewer, CAST(1 AS bit) IsAuthor, Name 
    FROM
        Surveys
    UNION
    SELECT
        SurveyID, ID, UserID, IsViewer, IsAuthor, NULL AS Name
    FROM
        RightsOnSurveys
GO

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[vRightsOnSurveys]
```

Here is output of this view:

[image]

and selecting from this view in the stored procedure for front end where `SurveyID` and `UserID` could be null or have data

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserRightsOnSurveys]
    (@SurveyID int = NULL,
     @UserID int = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT    
        ID, UserID, SurveyID, ros.IsViewer, IsAuthor, ros.Name
    FROM
        vRightsOnSurveys ros 
    WHERE
        (ros.SurveyID = @SurveyID OR @SurveyID IS NULL) 
        AND (ros.UserID = @UserID OR @UserID IS NULL)
END
```

With this procedure, I am not getting results as per my requirements.

Can somebody please help me? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You need `left join` in the view as follows:

```
alter view [dbo].[vRightsOnSurveys]
as
select  s.ID SurveyID, 
        coalesce(r.id,0) ID,  
        coalesce(r.userid,-1) UserID,
        coalesce(r.isviewer,cast(1 as bit)) IsViewer, 
        coaleace(r.isauthor,cast(1 as bit)) IsAuthor, 
        s.Name 
from    Surveys s
left Join    rightonsurvey r on r.surveyid = s.id;
```

Comment: This scenerio is working only for those users who submitted one or two surveys.Its not working if users there is not any user in rightonsurvey table. please help me and the checkboxes should be unchecked

Answer (score 0):

I have to change my whole query and got my results as per my requirements here is the query..

```
 select usr.ID as UserID,usr.Login,usr.Name as UserName, sur.ID as SurveyID,sur.Name
  ,ISNULL((select r.ID from RightsOnSurveys  r where r.UserID = usr.ID and r.SurveyID 
 = sur.ID),0) as ID
  ,ISNULL((select r.IsViewer from RightsOnSurveys  r where r.UserID = usr.ID and 
   r.SurveyID = sur.ID),cast(0 as bit)) as IsViewer
   ,ISNULL((select r.IsAuthor from RightsOnSurveys  r where r.UserID = usr.ID and 
   r.SurveyID = sur.ID),cast(0 as bit)) as IsAuthor
    from Users usr,Surveys sur
```